# How to merge 2 mvc2 project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

Is there a way to merge 2 mvc 2 project.?

I already try with areas, but that doesn't work.

These 2 projects doesn't have the same structure tree and are not in the same namespace. This is 2 different project made by 2 differents people.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging 2 mvc projects is not straight forward as it is with MVC and webforms, the problem here is that the MVC runtime uses its default naming convention for controllers, Actions and views names and it looks in different locations (looks in View/Shared etc folders) by those names...so having different namespaces will not help either...if you have controllers with same names, then you will have to set one of them as partial and also you will have to make sure that there are no duplicate action methods...

Comment: As you mention here, when we got two controller with the same name, I need to put the namespace in the maproute.